# How to save files in pc rather than sdcard through USB

Tags: android

i want to have import and export functionality in my application.
Basically i want to save and retrieve files not in my mobile but in my pc.So that when I connect my phone to pc through USB and click on import button my files automatically import to my application then i can use data inside them and same will be for export.The location is predefined.
I don't know whether simple INPUT/OUTPUT streams can help me or not because i have tried all but failed and i am not getting any method in android API too. 
I don't know whether this functionality is in android or not because when we connect mobile to pc then our sd card is treated as another drive in pc.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into Android that gives the device access to anything on the host PC.

Comment: perhaps i don.t know that what is the right way..but there must be some thing. because i have seen some thing like adb pull and push please tell me what does they do .any ways thank you for the reply

Comment: i have seen some thing like adb pull and push commands..can they be helpful for me..please tell me..because there must be some thing..i know i m not the first person the be in this kind of situation

Comment: @kshitij: "because i have seen some thing like adb pull and push" -- these go from the PC to the device, not from the device to the PC. "U should also look at this" -- thank you for insulting me.